# Date comparison query php sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I'm struggling to compare dates in an sql query on 2 counts - I've looked around at `strtotime` / date / from unixtime etc, but can't quite work it out.

`$currentday` is a date string in the format of `2013-12-29`

Enddate is a 'date' type sql string - in the format `0000-00-00` (sometimes with dates and other times `null`)

1. I only want to retrieve those dates where the current date is before the end date - but the sql query I have is returning all of them.
2. I know it is slower, but I tried to achieve it in the code - this worked... however I found another problem. I want to be able to say if 'enddate' is after the current date OR enddate is null (0000-00-00) then print.. etc - However I can't get the null to work.

Here is the code:

```
///Find all regular payments ordered by amount descending
$check = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM 
 regular 
WHERE
 enddate >= ".$currentday." AND
 userid = ".$varuserid."
 ORDER BY amount desc
");

if($check === FALSE) {
     die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
} else {

  $regcheck = array(); //Assign details of valid regular payments for the user to an array 
  while($val=mysql_fetch_array($check)) {

    //SHOULD BE LIMITED BY SQL QUERY - Don't understand why it isnt??
    if (($val['enddate'] > $currentday) || (!$val['enddate'])) {
      print $val['enddate'].'?'.$currentday.'<br/>';
      //ERROR - NOT SURE WHY THIS SHOWS UP FROM THE SQL QUERY?
    } else {
      print 'err'.$val['enddate'].'?'.$currentday.'<br/>';  
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear what the end goal is, but have adjusted your MySQL to accommodate `0000-00-00` and `NULL` dates.

```
$check = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM 
  regular 
WHERE
  (enddate >= '" . $currentday . "' AND
  enddate IS NOT NULL AND
  enddate != '0000-00-00') AND
  userid = ".$varuserid."
  ORDER BY amount desc
");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote strings:

```
WHERE enddate >= '".$currentday."' AND ...
```

Comment: Thankyou! I'd tried '$currentday' $currentday '.$currentday.' etc etc.... That must be the only one I hadn't tried but solves it. 2 hours of hunting finished and I can now go to bed :) - With thanks to the guy below too, I'll use:    (enddate >= '" . $currentday . "' OR
  enddate = '0000-00-00') AND